# Everywhere, since the beginning

Tags: riddle

I can be said to go round and round,
But I am everywhere, and somewhere at once.
You may think you know everything about me,
But you really can’t.
You need me in your life,
But you don’t want me to stay.
Wield me right, and I’ll open doors,
But use me wrong, and I’ll make pain.

What am I?

Hint:

> You cannot see me,
>   But, I can let you see.
>   I can pull things together,
>   But, I can push them apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> an electron

I can be said to go round and round,

> Electrons "orbit" the nucleus

But I am everywhere, and somewhere at once.

> Electrons have both wave-like and particle-like properties

You may think you know everything about me,
But you really can’t.

> There are [limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) to what we can know about an electron's properties

You need me in your life,

> People depend on electricity

But you don’t want me to stay.

> The current needs to be moving

Wield me right, and I’ll open doors,

> Electronic keys

But use me wrong, and I’ll make pain.

> Electric shock

Hints: You cannot see me,

> Way too small for the naked eye

But, I can let you see.

> Electric lights

I can pull things together,
But, I can push them apart.

> Electromagnets

Title: Everywhere, since the beginning

> There have been electrons all over the universe, since forever

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Time

I can be said to go round and round,

> 'Round the clock.

But I am everywhere, and somewhere at once.

> It's always a certain time somewhere.

You may think you know everything about me,

> History.

But you really can’t.

> There are a lot of mysteries.

You need me in your life,

> Well, yeah.

But you don’t want me to stay.

> You may want to get something over with.

Wield me right, and I’ll open doors,

> Learn a skill and get a job.

But use me wrong, and I’ll make pain.

> You may get behind.

And

> It has been everywhere since the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Could the answer be

> A **wheel**?

`I can be said to go round and round,`

> *"The* ***wheels*** *on the bus go* ***round and round***${}$*..."*

`But I am everywhere and somewhere at once.`

> This is a reference to the **colour wheel**. Colour is all around us — it is **everywhere** — but can be found somewhere on a **wheel**.

`You may think you know everything about me,`

> **Everyone knows** what a wheel is, right...?

`But you really can't.`

> Well, you **don't know** when your wheel is gonna become **flat** (i.e. if you are driving). Also, the word "wheel" sounds like "really".

`You need me in your life,`

> Whether you drive or catch public transport or use an electric toothbrush or like to put your face in front of the fan, you need to use some kind of **wheel mechanism** — even boats need wheels to steer!

`But you don't want me to stay.`

> If wheels just **stayed** as they are **without rotating**, how would they ever put things into motion?

`Wield me right and I'll open doors,`

> To **open a door** with a key, you have to turn the key to the **right**. The dead bolt lock inside the doorknob is unlocked this way through a wheel mechanism.

`But use me wrong and I'll make pain.`

> That is why we have **speed limits** and warnings of **wet roads** (and **slopes or elevators**, as opposed to stairs, for those who require a **wheelchair**). At the end of the day, [**life is like a wheel**](http://www.lessons4living.com/life%20is%20like.htm).

---

**Title:**

`Everywhere, since the beginning.`

> There are many metaphorical/philosophical "wheels" that help to find balance in life, and all that, (like the [Yin $\&$ Yang](https://www.ancient.eu/Yin_and_Yang/)), so that could be answer if we are talking about the beginning of our **life**. 
>  
>  But if we are talking about the beginning of ***all*** **life**, then how about...

> ...the wheel-like shape of an atom (to the eye at least)! Here is the first ever picture of an atom.

> Do you see it? $$$$ [image: Atom] $$$$ The universe, itself, is literally a spinning ball, much like a wheel anyway. However, this potential explanation for the title is a bit of a stretch, I must admit.

Comment: Not quite, but amazing answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

It could be (partial answer)

> Zero (0)

As,

I can be said to go round and round,

> Obvious

But I am everywhere, and somewhere at once.

> To be provided...

You may think you know everything about me,
But you really can’t.

> It was the last introduced digit in decimal number system and we are not able to decide what is the value of *divide by zero*

You need me in your life,

> Yes, it is very much needed for enabling us to count further and further concisely.

But you don’t want me to stay.

> Only having zero may not be a desirable situation

Wield me right, and I’ll open doors,

> Place value ( by adding it at right hand side, one number gets ten fold and so on..)

But use me wrong, and I’ll make pain

> If not properly placed, it dwindles/ makes no impact, in numbers.

Comment: Good answer, but it’s not what I’m looking for. Some of these lines are more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Another partial answer:

> Infinity goes round and round (I guess)
>
> Infinity is everywhere but also somewhere
>
> You can't know everything about infinity
>
> Definitely need infinity
>
> Not really easy to get your head around
>
> Infinity stones powers
>
> Infinity stones destroying half of the universe?

Comment: Not quite, but good answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> Electromagnetic radiation? *(Specifically from our sun)*

I can be said to go round and round,

> The sun is our source of radiation providing heat and light, and *appears* to go around the earth (although it is earth that is revolving.

But I am everywhere, and somewhere at once.

> The light from our sun never goes away, so it could be said to be everywhere - and it is always daylight "somewhere" in the world.

You may think you know everything about me,
But you really can’t.

> We know a lot about the sun and other stars like it, and we know more about it now than we ever have thanks to science on earth. But we can never get close enough to study it, so everything in theoretical.

You need me in your life,
But you don’t want me to stay.

> We couldn't survive without the heat and light of our sun; and yet we couldn't sleep if it was there all the time so we welcome the night too.

Wield me right, and I’ll open doors,

> Not 100% sure about this bit - but "opening doors" could be metaphorical. Harnessing or "wielding" the power from our sun could "open the door" to a future of clean renewable energy. OR perhaps it is more literal, referring to automatic doors? The sensors that trigger automatic doors detect movement using light/infrared.

But use me wrong, and I’ll make pain.

> Sunburn? That hurts.

You cannot see me,
But, I can let you see.

> You can't actually *see* the whole of the electromagnetic spectrum, but it allows us to see as it is diffused into the visible light spectrum.

I can pull things together,
But, I can push them apart.

> Electromagnetism obviously attracts and repels.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Air

I can be said to go round and round

> Air circulates the earth as it rotates

But I am everywhere, and somewhere at once.

> Air is everywhere and somewhere

You may think you know everything about me,

> To predict air/wind patterns and weather around globe

But you really can’t.

> Weather events (air) unpredictable exactly

You need me in your life,

> We need air to breath

But you don’t want me to stay.

> Air inhaled has to come out

Wield me right, and I’ll open doors,

> air operated machines, like pneumatic machines

But use me wrong, and I’ll make pain.

> pressurized air without caution may burst/damage